# This script is not working, the page its on only refreshes when submited, and does not insert into the database

Tags: php, html, sql

*starts the session*

```
<? session_start();
```

*loads if they submitted or not*

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
```

*checks if they are logged in*

```
if (!(isset($_SESSION['sess_user']) || $_SESSION['sess_user'] == '')) {
header("location:index.php");
}
```

*connects to database*

```
$dbcon = mysqli_connect('mysql6.000webhost.com', 'a8186782_db',     'password1', 'a8186782_db') or die(mysqli_error($dbcon));
```

*gives easier way to comprehend meanings*

```
$a1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['a1']);
$a2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['a2']);
$a3 = $_SESSION['sess_user'];
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_SESSION['sess_user']);
```

*checks if they have entered both inserts correctly*

```
if ($a1 <> $a2) { echo "Your fraternity names do not match.";}

*if they have then this will happen*

else if (mysqli_query($dbcon, "UPDATE groups SET groupname ='$a1'"));
else if (mysqli_query($dbcon, "UPDATE groups SET founder ='$a3'"))
{
echo "Your fraternity has been created. You will now be logged out.";
echo "<META http-equiv='refresh' content='3;URL=logout.php'>";
}
```

*if something is wrong then this will happen*

```
else { mysqli_error($dbcon); }
mysqli_close($dbcon);
}
?>
```

Comment: Please, explain the problem where and what you are facing in your description

Comment: okay, this is for a form, an html form, if they confirm the fraternity name they want to create, the code above will acknowledge the confirmation of the fraternity. instead of inserting into the database the page is just reloading.. why?

Comment: I did not vote down your question. And please explain your problem in the description. We gave title just for the overview of the problem

Comment: there might issues with session, please check your session variables.

Comment: Gosh!! i told you to explain problem in your description not in title

Comment: no issue with session

Comment: how would i change this script to INSERT instead of UPDATE

Answer (score 0):

You're not inserting, only updating. And you're actually updating ALL records, not just one. I'd recommend you take a look at some [SQL tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp), and then some [PHP tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp), before proceeding.

To insert, you'll want something like the following:

`INSERT INTO groups (groupname, founder) VALUES ('coolest group', 'the boss');`

To help with your PHP coding:

- Variable names $a1, $a2 aren't particularly clear. Use meaningful names!
- Should use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php), rather than concatenating strings.
- Use a consistent code style. Your whitespace (e.g. `if (` versus `if(`) and braces (`{` on the same line as the opening conditional, then on a different line in another instance) are inconsistent.
- Probably don't use the shortcut `<?` tag. Instead, use `<?php`.